# Increment the value of a variable on button click

Tags: reactjs

I have two JS files called `App.Js` and `index.js`. I want to increment the value of a `count` variable each time I click a button. I render the html element in `index.js` and I wrote the `onclick` method code in `App.js`. But it is not working. This is the code I've have tried with:

**App.js**

[image]

**index.js**

[image]

Comment: Your `onClick` method is not defined in right component

Comment: Please paste the code in the question itself, that will help to debug.

Comment: Please include code as text and not as image along with the question.

Comment: sorry this was the first time i am posting questions here

Answer (score 0):

Move the button inside the App component. inside the index.js just render the App.

Comment: Its worked am a beginner in react js. Thank you so  much

Answer (score 0):

Please update your App component as follows :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count:0
    }
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      return {
       count: prevState.count+1
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.state.count}</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, remove the class Count from index.js as it is unused.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the method in the `App` component .Define the button in the same component:

```
 class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
            super(props)
    this.state={count:0}
     this.handeleClick=this.handeleClick.bind(this);
    }
    
    handeleClick(){
    this.setState(prevState=>
    return {
           count: prevState.count+1
          }
    )
     render() {
        return (
        <button onClick={this.handeleClick}>{this.state.count}</button>
        )
      }
 }
export default App
```

And so on:

```
class Count extends Component {
render() {
  return (
   <App/>
  )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<Count />, document.getElementById('root'));
```